# Pass the .xslx file from WebAPI to Angular2+ project and save it from the browser

Tags: excel, angular, file, asp.net-web-api

I have an .xslx file in MemoryStream in ASP.NET WebAPI. I need to send it to the JavaScript front-end (Angular4) where I will let the user save it with **[file-saver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver)** package.

I have tried returning an instance of MemoryStream like so

```
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheet = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(memoryStream, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);

spreadsheet.AddWorkbookPart();
spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Workbook();
spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Append(new BookViews(new WorkbookView()));
WorksheetPart newWorksheetPart = spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
Sheet sheet = new Sheet() { Id = spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(newWorksheetPart), SheetId = worksheetNumber, Name = "Random Sheet Name" };
sheets.Append(sheet);
spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Save();

return new JsonResult()
    {
        Data = memoryStream,
        JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
    };
```

**[file-saver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver)** provides a method for saving files from the browser: **saveAs()**. It expects a Blob() object as the first parameter. So I tried:

```
saveAs(new Blob([data.Data], {type: 'application/octet-stream'}), "Report.xlsx");
```

This does save the file, however when I try opening it, I get the following message:

*Excel cannot open the file 'Report.xslx' because the file format or file extension is not valid.*

**The file appears to be empty on opening.**

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Is your "excel file" really an actual Excel file, or something else (html table/CSV) with an Excel file extension?  If it's not an actual Excel file then Office is going to always give that warning.

Comment: The file is the actual Excel file created with OpenXML SDK in WebAPI.